# Why is there a drastic difference in meaning between *amused* and *bemused*?

Tags: meaning

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I have yet to find an exact match by search.

Both words use the same root of muse, which as a verb means to lose yourself in thought, ponder, etc.

So, clearly *bemuse* trades upon this usage, with *be* as an intensifier of a prefix meaning to really be lost in thought, bewildered, nonplussed, etc.

Why, then, is *amuse* to entertain?  The *a* prefix here means at (as derived from the Middle English and Old English).  And, if one were *at muse*, you would think them to be at a state of bewilderment, lost in thought, etc.

Or, is this meaning of muse related to the nine goddesses of Greek and Roman mythology who preside over the arts and sciences, and it means that you are at the muses?  It just strikes me as strange to mix an Middle English prefix with a Roman concept.

I guess it would suffice to say, I'm bemused by this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Evan Morris of Word Detective, [muse the noun has a different origin than muse the verb](http://www.word-detective.com/2013/02/bemused/). And the short answer is that they both referred to distracting people by confusing them. It's just that, over time, references to flashy things "amusing" the passer-by was changed to refer to a pleasant pasttime rather than bamboozling them.

Comment: I feel like I'm cheating a bit in that I'm largely restating Mr. Morris, but he really is an excellent source for things like this. Funnily enough, the person who asked that question in the link? That's one of my older brothers.

Comment: Restating others is what this site is all about.  For that matter, when you post something unsourced, many people down vote it despite its inherent validity.  This source was very  good.  My only complaint is that it would be nice to see some sourcing within Mr. Morris's article.  The quotations are without reference which always irks me!

Comment: I would ask, though, that you flesh this answer out a bit rather than rely upon the source to tell the story.  Links have a way of changing.